# How to Improve a report processing time (Django/MySQL)?

Tags: python, mysql, django, database-design, report

I'm looking for ideas on how to improve a report that takes up to 30 minutes to process on the server, I'm currently working with Django and MySQL but if there is a solution that requires changing the language or SQL database I'm open to it.

The report I'm talking about reads multiple excel files and insert all the rows from those files into a table (the report table) with a range from 12K to 15K records, the table has around 50 columns. This part doesn't take that much time.

Once I have all the records on the report table I start applying multiple phases of business logic so I end having something like this:

```
def create_report():
    business_logic_1()
    business_logic_2()
    business_logic_3()
    business_logic_4()
```

Each function of the *business_logic_X* does something very similar, it starts by doing a `ReportModel.objects.all()` and then it applies multiple calculations like checking dates, quantities, etc and updates the record. Since it's a 12K record table it quickly starts adding time to the complete report.

The reason I'm going multiple functions separately and no all processing in one pass it's because the logic from the first function needs to be completed so the logic on the next functions works (ex. the first function finds all related records and applies the same status for all of them.

The first thing that I know could be optimized is somehow caching the objects.all() instead of calling it in each function but I'm not sure how to pass it to the next function without saving the records first.

I already optimized the report a bit by using update_fields on the save method of the functions and that saved a bit of time.

My question is, is there a better approach to this kind of problem? Is Django/MySQL the right stack for this?

Comment: Let's see the SQL involved.

Answer (score 0):

What takes time is the business logic that you're doing in Django. So it does several round trips between the database and the application.

It sounds like there are several tables involved, so I would suggest that you write your query in raw sql and once you have the results you get that into the application, if you need it.

The orm has a method "raw" that you can use. Or you could drop down to even lower level and interface with Your database directly.

Unless I see more what you do, I can't give any more specific advice